# What is wrong with one of 3 SVG images that fill does not work on it?

Tags: css, svg

I have 3 SVG images, which are in [here](https://codepen.io/name1111/pen/NWqBYor). As you can notice, fill  **on hover** works correctly on two of them, but not the user.

It seems that it's not the img embedded in the  `<svg>` tag, it's normal svg picture.

At first I thought that this `<svg>` has some mistakes which I don't know and have tried to use some online resources to find those mistakes, but this didn't helped...

Could someone tell what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in the user icon you have `<circle>` and `<path>` elements that don't have any `fill`. In fact, the color that you should be changing is the `stroke` instead. If you add the following rule, then your user icon will show the desired hover state.

To avoid the circle and path styles from interfering with your other two icons, give the first SVG element a class, e.g. `user-icon`:

```
svg.user-icon:hover circle,
svg.user-icon:hover path {
  stroke: red;
}
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```css
svg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
svg:hover {
  fill: red !important;
}
svg.user-icon:hover circle,
svg.user-icon:hover path {
  stroke: red;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  place-items: center center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
<svg class="user-icon" id="6a8da56c-64cb-4c0d-b7e3-2b80c0db2d07" data-name="ICON" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="192" height="192" viewBox="0 0 192 192"><circle id="3ad8aabf-2066-47d6-9a2f-c027e5c19606" data-name="&lt;Pfad&gt;" cx="96" cy="63.91" r="36.09" fill="none" stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/><path id="243fad7b-53d4-4daa-93b6-31f40d832ead" data-name="&lt;Pfad&gt;" d="M156,164.1c-6.48-43.88-33.17-64.23-59.64-64.23S42.49,120.21,36,164.09" fill="none" stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/><rect width="192" height="192" fill="none"/></svg>
  
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M11.5,22C11.64,22 11.77,22 11.9,21.96C12.55,21.82 13.09,21.38 13.34,20.78C13.44,20.54 13.5,20.27 13.5,20H9.5A2,2 0 0,0 11.5,22M18,10.5C18,7.43 15.86,4.86 13,4.18V3.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 11.5,2A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 10,3.5V4.18C7.13,4.86 5,7.43 5,10.5V16L3,18V19H20V18L18,16M19.97,10H21.97C21.82,6.79 20.24,3.97 17.85,2.15L16.42,3.58C18.46,5 19.82,7.35 19.97,10M6.58,3.58L5.15,2.15C2.76,3.97 1.18,6.79 1,10H3C3.18,7.35 4.54,5 6.58,3.58Z"></path>
</svg>
  
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
</svg>
  
  
</div>
```

---

### Even better: CSS custom properties/variables

If you can actually change the inline SVG markup, I would suggest using CSS variables so you have better control over what property `fill` vs `stroke` should be changed. Simply replace all instances of `#333` in your markup to use `var(--icon-color`, then you can change the color freely as such:

```
svg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  --icon-color: #333;
}
svg:hover {
  --icon-color: red;
}
```

See example here:

```css
svg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  --icon-color: #333;
}

svg:hover {
  --icon-color: red;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  place-items: center center;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg id="6a8da56c-64cb-4c0d-b7e3-2b80c0db2d07" data-name="ICON" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="192" height="192" viewBox="0 0 192 192"><circle id="3ad8aabf-2066-47d6-9a2f-c027e5c19606" data-name="&lt;Pfad&gt;" cx="96" cy="63.91" r="36.09" fill="none" stroke="var(--icon-color)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/><path id="243fad7b-53d4-4daa-93b6-31f40d832ead" data-name="&lt;Pfad&gt;" d="M156,164.1c-6.48-43.88-33.17-64.23-59.64-64.23S42.49,120.21,36,164.09" fill="none" stroke="var(--icon-color)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/><rect width="192" height="192" fill="none"/></svg>

  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M11.5,22C11.64,22 11.77,22 11.9,21.96C12.55,21.82 13.09,21.38 13.34,20.78C13.44,20.54 13.5,20.27 13.5,20H9.5A2,2 0 0,0 11.5,22M18,10.5C18,7.43 15.86,4.86 13,4.18V3.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 11.5,2A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 10,3.5V4.18C7.13,4.86 5,7.43 5,10.5V16L3,18V19H20V18L18,16M19.97,10H21.97C21.82,6.79 20.24,3.97 17.85,2.15L16.42,3.58C18.46,5 19.82,7.35 19.97,10M6.58,3.58L5.15,2.15C2.76,3.97 1.18,6.79 1,10H3C3.18,7.35 4.54,5 6.58,3.58Z" fill="var(--icon-color)"></path>
</svg>

  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z" fill="var(--icon-color)"></path>
</svg>


</div>
```

Comment: Dude, you just saved my life, it works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Besides, could you tell me if it's good to use `<svg>` directly in the html or it's better to use a background-image instead?

Comment: It really depends on your use case. If you want to change the fill and manipulate the styles in the SVG, you *must* inline them--you cannot, for example, do what you're doing with SVG as background images.